# First TextView Overlaps the second one ,Android

Tags: android, textview, overlapping

I have 2 `TextViews` which I need to both horizontally side by side, like category + nummber of products for category. The code is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom ="10dp"
    android:background="@color/navigation_background_sub">


   <TextView

        android:id="@+id/category_name_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ebuy_color_navigation_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_name_second"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"

        android:id="@+id/category_number_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ebuy_color_navigation_number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the problem is that once the text for the first `TextView` is to long , the space left for the second is to little and the text is display in two ore more lines.

I have no reputation to post pictures so I am just trying to explain like below:

How it is:

Laptops (34)

Computer Software (1

```
               4                    
               )
```

How it should be:

Laptops (34)

Computer (14)

Software

Comment: You are using the same id for both TextViews. Make them unique and it should work

Comment: he is not using the same id. this wouldnt even be possible

Comment: Have you tried `layout_toEndOf` instead of `layout_toRightOf`?

Comment: but if there isnt enough space on the screen eventually it will be viewed in more lines

Comment: Sorry but the first id is **category_name_second** and the second id is **category_number_second**

Answer (score 0):

use

```
layout_toRightOf= "@id/category_name_second"
```

It may help you

Comment: this is what I have been using so far

Comment: can you remove the padding

Comment: actually the size u r assigning for the text is 22sp set it to 14 sp coz it shows it in a similar manner because of less space.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your `RelativeLayout` with a horizontal `LineraLayout` the available space will be distributed evenly among your text views. You can add a `weight` attribute to control the portion of each `TextView` in one line of length.

Comment: Yes it could be, but if use `LinearLayout` together with `weights`, if the text of the first `TextView` is too small , I am afraid the space between the two `TextView` would be too much, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you have not enough space at the horizontally line, this is why the text view display more lines.

You must define how much space you want for each Textview. If your layout is so simple like that, you can choose a linear layout to align better the textview's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_name_second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:text="Computers"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/ebuy_color_navigation_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_number_second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:text="(24)"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/ebuy_color_navigation_number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You must add also the property *singleLine* to avoid the textview's display more lines. As you see, using the weight you can set the proportional width for each component in the horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

In TextView When you use wrap_content android device will adjust its width and height(if you use wrap_content for height) according to data you put in (length of text). If text is not fix in textview then don't use wrap_content(only if you don't want that text automatically write in second line).So if first Textview has taken more than half space, second textview must adjust its height to show full text.There is no permanent solution of it, because this text line depends on device's size. if device's screen is larger to show both textview in single line it will show you unless it will increase height of second textview in your case.

you can also make different layout for all type of screen size and set text's size according to it. you can [check](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for supporting multiple screen size.